# Importing multiple store in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am using vue js with vue cli 3.

I have to import multiple store files (auth.js and mainStore.js) and I´d like to make 
that in the file main.js.

When run the app, I am get an error saying:

```
[vuex] unknown mutation type: SET_DRAWER
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the files I created:

//src/main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

//src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import modules from "./modules";

Vue.use(Vuex);
console.log(modules);
export default new Vuex.Store({ modules });
```

//src/store/modules.js

```
import { default as auth } from "./auth";
import { default as navbar } from "./mainStore";
export default {
  auth,
  navbar,
};
```

//src/store/auth.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default {
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null,
    isUserLoggedIn: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
      state.token = token;
      state.isUserLoggedIn = !!token;
    },
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setToken({ commit }, token) {
      commit("setToken", token);
    },
    setUser({ commit }, user) {
      commit("setUser", user);
    },
  },
  namespaced: true,
};
```

//src/store/mainStore.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default {
  state: {
    barColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)",
    barImage:
      "https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg",
    drawer: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BAR_IMAGE(state, payload) {
      state.barImage = payload;
    },
    SET_DRAWER(state, payload) {
      state.drawer = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  namespaced: true,
};
```

//Navbar.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar id="app-bar" absolute app flat height="75">
    <v-btn class="mr-3" elevation="1" fab small @click="setDrawer(!drawer)">
      <v-icon v-if="value">
        mdi-view-quilt
      </v-icon>

      <v-icon v-else>
        mdi-dots-vertical
      </v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-toolbar-title
      class="hidden-sm-and-down font-weight-light"
      v-text="$route.name"
    />

    <v-spacer />

    <v-btn class="ml-2" min-width="0" text to="/pages/user">
      <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
// Components
import { mapState, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "DashboardCoreAppBar",

  components: {},

  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState(["drawer"]),
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      setDrawer: "SET_DRAWER",
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

//Drawer.vue

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    id="core-navigation-drawer"
    v-model="drawer"
    :dark="barColor !== 'rgba(228, 226, 226, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'"
    :expand-on-hover="expandOnHover"
    :right="$vuetify.rtl"
    :src="barImage"
    mobile-break-point="960"
    app
    width="260"
    v-bind="$attrs"
  >
    <template v-slot:img="props">
      <v-img :gradient="`to bottom, ${barColor}`" v-bind="props" />
    </template>

    <v-divider class="mb-1" />

    <v-list dense nav>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-avatar class="align-self-center" color="white" contain>
          <v-img
            src="https://demos.creative-tim.com/vuetify-material-dashboard/favicon.ico"
            max-height="30"
          />
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title
            style="height:20px;"
            class="title"
            v-text="profile.title"
          />
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>

    <v-divider class="mb-2" />

    <v-list dense nav>
      <v-list-item
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.title"
        link
        router
        :to="item.to"
      >
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>

        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
// Utilities
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "DashboardCoreDrawer",

  props: {
    expandOnHover: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",
        title: "Dashboard",
        to: "/",
      },
      {
        icon: "mdi-account",
        title: "Usuários",
        to: "/pages/user",
      },
      {
        title: "Clientes",
        icon: "mdi-map-marker",
        to: "/maps/google-maps",
      },
      {
        title: "Convênios",
        icon: "mdi-clipboard-outline",
        to: "/convenios",
      },
      {
        title: "Planos",
        icon: "mdi-format-font",
        to: "/components/typography",
      },
      {
        title: "Tabelas",
        icon: "mdi-chart-bubble",
        to: "/components/icons",
      },
      {
        title: "Atendimento",
        icon: "mdi-bell",
        to: "/components/notifications",
      },
    ],
  }),

  computed: {
    ...mapState(["barColor", "barImage"]),
    drawer: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.drawer;
      },
      set(val) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
        debugger;
        this.$store.commit("SET_DRAWER", val);
      },
    },
    computedItems() {
      return this.items.map(this.mapItem);
    },
    profile() {
      return {
        avatar: true,
        title: "Gestan",
      };
    },
  },

  methods: {
    mapItem(item) {
      return {
        ...item,
        children: item.children ? item.children.map(this.mapItem) : undefined,
        title: item.title,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring your stores as namespaced, the mutation type is: `navbar/SET_DRAWER`. You don't have a SET_DRAWER mutation.

Comment: Thank you. An information please. If I want to use SET_DRAWER without navbar prefix, what could I change to achieve it?

Comment: set namespaced: false in your store

Comment: Sorry, my friend, But If do that, I get no error. But when I click on drawer button, nothing happends. I attached my Navbar.vue

Comment: I added Drawer.vue  as well

Comment: The initial value of drawer is null. I think it should be a boolean value for the toggle to work.

Comment: If I get rid multiple store and I use the next it works. import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    barColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)",
    barImage:
      "https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg",
    drawer: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BAR_IMAGE(state, payload) {
      state.barImage = payload;
    },
    SET_DRAWER(state, payload) {
      state.drawer = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
});

Comment: So, I think the problem is with multiple store

Comment: I have tried: computed: {
    ...mapState("navbar", ["drawer"]),
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations("navbar", ["SET_DRAWER"]),
  },   But no look with multiple store

Comment: Also, try removing Vue.use(Vuex) from store modules, and leave only in the main store.

Comment: I have the same problem